# Codeigniter modules checking with ajax

Tags: codeigniter, module, conditional-statements, pyrocms

Although i can't find a title to fit this need but here is the problem.

I have an existing module called Files. when i use this module some javascript runs and creates thumbs for different kind of files. It is run on windown load.
Now i am developing a module called File Links.
In this module i need to create thumbs on windows load.
I have copied the code from Files module.
Here is some code

```
public function folder_contents()
{
    $parent = $this->input->post('parent');
    echo json_encode(Files::folder_contents($parent));
}
```

This takes the parent parameter coming from ajax request and gets the folder contents.
I want to display all files. For this i have created another method of model that fetches all files.
Now the problem is that while being in File Link Module on load ajax request runs and 
hits the method above. 
Here is what i have tried

```
public function folder_contents()
{
    $parent = $this->input->post('parent');
    $modules    =   $this->router->fetch_module();

    if($modules == 'files'){
        echo json_encode(Files::folder_contents($parent));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(Files::getAllFiles());
    }
}
```

In this method i am checking module name if it is not files then get all files but when ever this method is called module is always files. This method resides in Files Controller. And other thing is that i dont  want to write ajax request to point some where else because it is pre-maid and works great.
Now how can i set some condition which will let getAllFiles() run.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the module always shows as 'files' is because the ajax request *does* call the Files module regardless of which module triggered the ajax request. It is a separate request.

To get this working you can use the $parent value to determine whether or not you want all files or just the ones with a certain parent folder returned. If you remove the POST value from your custom ajax call then folder_contents() will return all files as shown below.

```
public function folder_contents()
{
    $parent = $this->input->post('parent');

    if($parent){
        echo json_encode(Files::folder_contents($parent));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(Files::getAllFiles());
    }
}
```

Since the default ajax call POSTs the folder id it will still return only the files from that folder.